# I got an error on every command in docker , whatever the command is , I've tried to delete the docker engine and docker desktop (In Ubuntu))

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run a docker command after a docker update but i couldn't

examples :

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started
unexpected end of JSON input
```

```
$docker -v
unexpected end of JSON input
```

I have delete docker files and reinstall but no result

[i HAVE INSTALL THE DOCKER DESKTOP USING THE OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/)

[LINK TO THE ENGINE INSTALLATION DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

Comment: `type docker` and also show the exact steps you performed to install docker and version that was installed.

Comment: seems like your docker service is not running . You can restart the docker service

Comment: @BMitch ,I've the last version of docker ```$ sudo docker -v```
Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f, I can now run docker commands but I've to use the sudo else I'll have the same error

Comment: @SumeetKumarYadav  , No the docker engine is already running (using docker desktop)

Comment: When I use the sudo command , I can use docker normally  ** but** it seems like it is not the same images, containers ... those appear in docker desktop

Comment: Please include the output of `type docker` and `env | grep DOCKER` both as your user, and root (opening a root shell using sudo -s).

Comment: Also include the exact steps used to install docker. This should be placed in your question (use the edit link above).

Comment: ```$ type docker```
docker is hashed (/usr/local/bin/docker)

Comment: env | grep DOCKER with the sudo and without it i get no result